# TCPDF optimize performance

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've done a lot of searching and testing. My task is to optimize PDF generation form HTML.

My code is:

```
<?php
define('K_TCPDF_EXTERNAL_CONFIG', true); 

require('static_config.php');
require("hipero_pdf.class.php");

$pdf = new hipero_TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_IMAGE, PDF_HEADER_IMAGE_WIDTH);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);

$pdf->writeHTML(PDF_SYNEO_HTML, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output('../../Content/Offers/Generated/'.PDF_SYNEO_FILENAME.'.pdf');
?>
```

My HTML is a bit messy, but test shows this is have almost no impact on performance.

Every peace of code take less than 1 sek. to be parsed. Only this take longer:

$pdf->AddPage - 3 sek.

$pdf->writeHTML - 9 sek.

$pdf->Output - 5 sek.

This is on IIS server (shared hosting).

Please tell me how to optimize this methods. I have no more ideas :/.

Comment: That sounds unusually long, seeing as you are not adding anything big to the document... Not sure whether there is any way to optimize this, though. It could be that the web space simply *is* that slow.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to suggest ways to optimize the methods without seeing/getting an explanation of how they work.

Answer (score 3):

At TCPDF website, there's a page which advises avoiding the use of writeHTML if possible. Other than that, it also advises avoiding use big HTML blocks.
There's more at http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php where they explain you can turn off additional options to make rendering faster.

Comment: The link no longer seems to work

Comment: at least it still can be found here: [webarchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20160625061939/http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php)

Answer (score 2):

I also had an issue with TCPDF performance. I followed the guidelines cited at http://www.tcpdf.org/performances.php. What I could take from it :

- writeHTML() made a big difference instead of cell(), but only for already short times. It divided by 5 the time taken for pieces that didn't take more than 5 seconds. But above that, it didn't make much of a difference.
- on the contrary, cutting big pieces in small worked really well for me. I tried to cut big pieces into smaller ones, and it seemed that the optimal was around 5000 characters per piece. It enabled me to bring a pdf generation from 60 seconds to 20 seconds, and 7 seconds on my server.

Hope it helps !

Comment: how do i cut big pieces of code in small, any example ? I need to understand this